# Как получить первый элемент массива в моем случае?

Tags: php

Вот код

```
foreach ($manga as $key => $item) {
    if($g == $item["glava"] || $glavaNextRename == true){
        $glavaNextRename = true;  
        if($g != $item["glava"]){
            $glavaNext = $item["glava"]; print $item["glava"];
            $glavaNextRename = false;
        }
    }
}
```

print выводит два элемента, первый 0, второй 26. Но почему-то переменной $glavaNext присваивается 26, а не 0. Почему так?

Comment: потому что в условие заходит два раза, первый раз когда ноль, второй раз когда 26 и соответственно26 перезаписывает 0

Comment: Вот в чем дело, не подскажешь как можно тогда остановить цикл при получении первого значения?

Comment: ..........break;

Comment: Пробовал. Тогда сразу всё идет по одному месту. Скорее нужно найти как записать конкретно первый элемент в переменную.

Comment: if $key === 0  ..........если числовые ключи...... если не числовые....... то завести счётчик $i

Comment: if($g == $item["glava"] || $glavaNextRename == true){
            $glavaNextRename = true;   
            if($g != $item["glava"]){
            if (++$i == 1)
             $glavaNext = $item["glava"]; 
                $glavaNextRename = false;  
            } 
        }
         

СПАСИБО! Все работает! И сорян за идиотские вопросы, учусь.